# Keep on getting "Can't expand stack segment by 16 bytes to 524288 bytes. Use -lstack # with # > 524288"

Tags: mips

```
    .data
    list:       .space 1000
    Left:       .space 1000
    Right:      .space 1000
    n:      .word 0
    arraySize:  .word 0
    arrayEndAddress:.word 0
    prompt1:    .asciiz "Enter n: "
    prompt2:    .asciiz "Enter element " 
    dialog1:    .asciiz "The size of array entered is not power of 2!"
    dialog2:    .asciiz "The sorted list is: "
    space:      .asciiz " " 
    colon:      .asciiz ": "
    eol:        .asciiz "\n"
    dummy:      .asciiz "Blah Blah Blah"
.text 
main:
    la $a0, prompt1
    li $v0, 4 
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    sw $v0, n
    #move $t0, $v0
    #move $t1, $v0
    lw $t1, n
    sll  $t1, $t1, 2
    li $t2, 1
    la $t0, list
    writeElements:
        beq $t1, $zero, done

        la $a0,prompt2
        li $v0, 4
        syscall

        move $a0, $t2
        li $v0, 1
        syscall 

        la $a0,colon
        li $v0, 4
        syscall 

        li $v0, 5
        syscall

        sw $v0, 0($t0)
        add $t0, $t0, 4
        sub $t1, $t1, 4
        add $t2, $t2, 1
        j writeElements
    done:

        sw $t0, arrayEndAddress
        la $t1, list
        sub $t0, $t0, $t1
        sw $t0, arraySize 
        jal mergeSort
    jal printArray
    j exit
exit:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

mergeSort:
        add $sp, $sp, -4
        sw $ra, 0($sp)
        #la $a0, list
        lw $t0, n #get the number of elements
        li $t1, 1 #curr_size
        sub $t0, $t0, 1

        for1:
            sleu $s5, $t1, $t0
            beqz $s5 endFor1
            # $t2=left_start
            # $t4=mid
            # $t5=right_end
            #li $t2, 0
            #li $t4, 0
            #li $t5, 0
            and  $t2, $t2, 0
            and $t4, $t4, 0
            and $t5, $t5, 0
            for2:
                sltu $s6, $t2, $t0
                beqz  $s6, endfor2
                addu $t4, $t2, $t1 
                subu $t4, $t4, 1

                sll $t5,  $t1,1
                addu  $t5,$t5, $t2
                subu $t5, $t5, 1


                findMin: blt $t5, $t0, min
                    move $t5, $t0
                min:
                    move $t5, $t5
                #list,$t2, $t4, $t5
                jal merge
                sll $s1, $t1, 1
                addu $t2, $t2, $s1
                j for2
            endfor2:
                sll $t1, $t1,1
                j for1
        endFor1:
            b doneMergeSort
doneMergeSort:
        lw $ra, 0($sp)
        jr $ra
merge:

        # params: list, l=$t2, m=$t4, r=$t5
        add $sp, $sp, -12
        sw $ra, 0($sp)
        sw $s1, 4($sp)
        sw $t2, 8($sp)
        sw $t1, 12($sp)
        #sw $t0, 16($sp)


        #ori $t0, $zero, 0 #n1
        #ori $t3, $0, 0 #n2

        addiu $t9, $t4, 1
        subu $t9, $t9, $t2
        subu  $t3, $t5, $t4

        li $s1, 0 #i
        li $t7, 0#j
        sll $t7, $t7, 2
        LeftInput:
            bge $s1, $t9, doneLeft
            add $s2, $t2, $s1
            sll $s2,$s2,2
            lw $s3, list($s2)
            sw $s3, Left($t7)
            add $s1, $s1, 1
            add $t7, $t7, 4

            j LeftInput
        doneLeft:
            li $s1, 0
            li $t7, 0
            #sll $t6, $t3, 2
            j RightInput

        RightInput:
            bge $s1, $t3, combine
            #bge $t7, $t6, combine
            add $s2, $t4, 1
            add $s2, $s2, $s1
            sll $s2, $s2, 2
            lw $s3, list($s2)
            add $t7,$t7, $s1
            sll $t7, $t7, 2
            sw $s3, Right($t7)
            add $s1, $s1, 1
            j RightInput
        combine:
            #t0=n1, $t2=l, $t3=n2
            li $t1, 0 #actual memory address
            li $t7, 0 #i=0
            li $t4, 0 #actual memory address
            li $t8, 0 #j
            sll $t5, $t2, 2 #$t2=$t5=k=l
            while1:
                bge $t7, $t9, while2
                bge $t8, $t3, while2

                sll $t1, $t7, 2
                sll $t4, $t8, 2
                lw $s1, Left($t1)
                lw $s2, Right($t4)
                if1:
                    bgt $s1, $s2, else1
                    #sll $t1,$t7, 2
                    lw $s3, Left($t1)
                    #sll $t5, $t7, 2
                    sw $s3, list($t5)
                    add $t7, $t7, 1
                    j whileLoop1
                else1:
                    #sll $t4,$t8, 2
                    lw $s3, Right($t4)
                    #sll $t5, $t8, 2
                    sw $s3, list($t5)
                    add $t8, $t8, 1
                    j whileLoop1
            whileLoop1:
                add $t5, $t5, 4
                j while1
            while2:
                bge $t7, $t9, while3
                sll $t1,$t7, 2
                lw $s3, Left($t1)
                sw $s3, list($t5)
                add $t7, $t7, 1
                add $t5, $t5, 4
                j while2
            while3:
                bge $t8, $t3, combineDone
                sll $t4,$t8, 2
                lw $s3, Right($t4)
                sw $s3, list($t5)
                add $t8, $t8, 1
                add $t5, $t5, 4
                j while3
        combineDone:
            j doneMerge
doneMerge:
        #la $a0, dummy
        #   li $v0, 4
        #   syscall
        #   la $a0, eol
        #   li $v0, 4
        #   syscall
        lw $ra, 0($sp)
        lw $s1, 8($sp)
        lw $t2, 4($sp)
        lw $t1, 12($sp)
        #lw $t0, 16($sp)
        jr $ra

printArray:
    #add $sp, $sp,-4
    la $a0, dialog2
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    li $t0, 0
    lw $t1, n
    sll $t1, $t1, 2
    loop:
        bge $t0, $t1, donePrint
        lw $a0, list($t0)
        li $v0, 1
        syscall

        la $a0, space
        li $v0, 4
        syscall 

        add $t0, $t0, 4
        j loop
    la $a0, eol
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
donePrint:
    #lw $ra, 0($sp)
    jr $ra
```

Comment: Is it QtSPIM? It doesn't like it when you move the stack pointer too far out of the normal stack area. Looks like your functions are not releasing the stack space that they're allocating (you are subtracting from the stack pointer in prologue, and never adding back in epilogue). As a result, probably inf. loop that ends in stack overflow.

Comment: Yes it is qtspim. So you suggest to add back to the stack in order to release the space?

Comment: Yeah, except it's not a suggestion, it's a requirement!

Comment: Thank you for the help! Much appreciated